# Modified manifest file partially not working

Tags: java, linux, makefile, manifest.mf

My manifest file (Manifest.txt) looks like this:

```
Main-Class: packageName.ClassName
Class-Path: jarFile1.jar:
```

However, when I execute the following command in Linux:

```
jar cfm jarFile.jar Manifest.txt -C Classes .
```

When I look at jarFile's META-INF/MANIFEST.MF I only see the modified main class, without the modified class path:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_71 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: packageName.className
```

Does anybody know why is this happening?

To be clear, my target was to get the following output:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_71 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: packageName.className
Class-Path: jarFile1.jar
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the first line, it looks like this: 
Main-Class: packageName.ClassName
Class-Path: jarFile1.jar:

Answer (score 0):

`jar` reads complete lines from the input manifest. Ensure that the file ends in  a carriage return otherwise the last line will be omitted